# Sum of tight frames also tight?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, wavelets

edit: More precise explanation

Let's consider a tight frame $w_1, w_2, w_3$ for all $v \in \Bbb{R}^4$. What happens if I perform the following operation: $\sum_{i=1}^{I} b_i \sum_{n=1}^{3} a_{n,i} w_{n}$ where all $b_i,a_{n,i} \in \Bbb{R}$

Is this still a tight frame? And if not in the general case, is there conditions under which it will be? For instance constraints on a and b, or a different sum operation like mentioned below. This is really a question about developing intuition, so even indirect comments would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The sum of frames being defined as the minkowski sum ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{f_k^{(i)} \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{H}$, where $i = 1,..., N$ be tight frames for $\mathcal{H}$ with frame bounds $A_i$. By definition, it holds for all $i = 1, ..., N$ that
$$ A_i \|f\|^2 = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |\langle f, f_k^{(i)} \rangle |^2. $$
Thus
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^N A_i \|f \|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |\langle f, f_k^{(i)} \rangle |^2, $$
and hence $\cup_{i = 1}^N \{f_k^{(i)} \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a tight frame for $\mathcal{H}$ with frame bound $\sum_{i = 1}^N A_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You did not take $a_{n,i},b_i$ into account in this proof. Can you elaborate a little bit if having a weighted sum changes anything?

Comment: And a second question, I thought per definition, the frame bounds have to be $A=B=1$ if the frame is tight. However, now it seems to me $\sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i$ can be any real number. Thus I am wondering if a renormalization is necessary to preserve the tightness in this case?

Comment: I see now that I did not exactly solve your question. Sorry for that. The title of the question indicates that you are interested in an ordinary sum of tight frames. Therefore, I thought the above would solve the problem. However, the main point is still that you add a finite number of identities, and hence the equality should not change. Regarding the tightness of a frame, this is by definition when $A = B$. The special case  $A = B =1$ is often called a normalised tight frame or a Parseval frame.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful already, I will give it a try and post the answer here. Regarding the tightness definition. Is a tight frame also always preserving the norm, even if it is not a parseval frame?